# Unterminated String Literal

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm getting an "Unterminated String Literal" error on all of these lines.

I am new to PHP so I'm a little lost.

Here's the code:

```
<a class="download" href="#" onclick="downloadSite('<?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['s']['url']; ?>
', <?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['s']['psid']; ?>
)"><img src="images/download.png" width="20" alt="Download" title="Download" /></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it PHP giving you the error or JavaScript?

Comment: @tsmeee has the most correct answer, likely. Since you're using PHP to echo values into a JavaScript method call, each argument needs to be escaped properly. Only numbers and variable references can be left "unquoted," and the second PHP value you echo isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding json_encode before echoing each php variable. Also if $this->_tpl_vars['s']['psid'] is string, then you should also put it inside the quotes:

```
<a class="download" href="#" onclick="downloadSite('<?php echo json_encode($this->_tpl_vars['s']['url']); ?>', '<?php echo json_encode($this->_tpl_vars['s']['psid']); ?>'
```

)">

Comment: it will encode a value to javascript notation. In your very case it will encode quotes that may appear in the string passed from PHP. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but I observe that you're opening a string with `'` right after `downloadSite`, and then also using `'` inside that string, and don't seem to be closing it.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, but argument should be closed on same line as opened ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to close first argument on same line

```
<a class="download" href="#" onclick="downloadSite('<?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['s']['url']; ?>'
```

Comment: This might have been better off as a comment instead of an answer :)