# syntaxerror unterminated string literal jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I get this weird error. It happens to be my PHP code that is embedded into jquery.

```
<?php $user=isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : NULL; //This returns a numeric value ?> 

<script>
  $("button[name='send_mail']").on('click',function(){
  var user = '<?php echo $user;?>'; // <----The Problem
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax/scripts/user_mail.php?u="+user,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        },
    });
  });
</script>
```

I tried both, single and double quotes. This piece code happens to work in some of my files and doesn't work in others.

Comment: Try it without the NULL

Comment: The question is: What's really in `$_GET['u']`? Try `var_dump` in PHP and take a look at the generated JavaScript code. Also you should never pass user input from `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc. directly to the output.

Comment: definitely as @insertusernamehere said. read more about **XSS**.

Comment: Or `escape` the string before print. What is in `$_GET`?

Comment: @monace19, still not working.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, my scripts are protected and only someone with a certain session name can run queries on the user id. And, if stack overflow is doing it, I don't there would be a problem

Comment: @sougata `$_GET` is just a user id

Comment: `floatval($var);` or `intval($var);` if it is just the user id.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, yeap. When I remove `var user`, everything works fine

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['u']` is just an integer? Can you show the generated JavaScript from the source code as what @insertusernamehere has mentioned (i.e. right click, then view source)?

Comment: Can you check the source and add what it is generating on that line?

Comment: Try alert(user); under the var user and tell us the output.

Comment: @sougata, I not that good at this and not sure what you really mean. I'm using a jquery.min file and the problem is at `:12:11`

Comment: @monace19, cant seem to `alert(user)`, same error.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine but when the $user has no value, it errors just like yours.

Comment: @user3284463. Right Click on the page -> View Source. Then check that code.

Comment: @user3284463. Try to initialize $user=0; first

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374020/unterminated-string-literal)

Comment: I think I found a way around it but not a solution to this. What I did is returned or echo `$user` to a hidden span and then `var user = $('#user_id_span').text()`

Comment: try `concat` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) it will throw exceptions if it fails for some reason that can help you

Comment: Hmm, by chance, does the browser actually show you the above code or is this the php code?  The reason I ask may explain your problem.

Comment: @neil the code above the `<script>` is just a PHP code.

Comment: @user3284463 That isn't my question.  I mean to ask if you see this code *in the browser*.  The browser shouldn't show any php tag.

Comment: @neil nope, the browser doesn't show any error. I get this error in the browser developer tools Console

Comment: Why is my question down voted? :(

Comment: Probably because it's impossible to help you without you checking the raw value of that variable, which you keep refusing to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php $user=isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : NULL;?>
<span id="user_id_span" style="display:none;"><?php echo $user; ?></span>

<script> 
  var user = $('#user_id_span').text();
</script>
```

If your output is more than just a single string or number or single line, this would not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $user = (!empty($_GET['u']))?intval($_GET['u']):0;
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
    console.log("User: " + <?php echo $user; ?>);
    // try to debug what is really in the variable
    var user = <?php echo $user; ?>;
    // same as <?= $user; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: @user3284463 Which one exactly? Do you have an error message?

Comment: @jan so there is no need to echo it??

Comment: @user3284463 But which one?

Comment: @jan `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Comment: @Jai: `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`.

Comment: Those lines with `<?php echo $user; ?>` will only work if `$user` is a number or a boolean.

Comment: @Cerbrus True, but the call to `intval()` assures it to actually **BE** it a number, so the code is perfectly fine.

Comment: So, what's the output of `intval` if it's parameter _isn't_ a number?

Comment: @Cerbrus Admittedly, it throws a warning, but the return value is always an integer (0 or 1 in case of an error). While this is surely just a side issue, consider the following code snippet: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9888486a01186d653ae3c07bacb1b1d1bf234ce

Comment: php never fails to... "amaze" me xD

Answer (score -1):

You have a rogue comma in this part of your code:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    }, //<--- here
});
```

It should be only:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: That won't cause any errors. In fact, that's perfectly valid JS.

Comment: @shadow Wizard, this is not it

Comment: @Cerbrus [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/6z9sq722/), though the error is different. (SyntaxError: Unexpected token)

Comment: @user3284463 so we can't really know what the problem is, since the part you posted is fine and for some odd reason you refuse to tell us the real value of `$user`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: In your example, you're adding a comma in a function call. The stray comma in your answer is just a training comma in an object. that'd different, and perfectly valid JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus OK, valid, but ugly in my opinion, so leaving this answer as "better practice advice".

Comment: Then it doesn't answer the question, and it's an opinion-based answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus feel free to downvote and flag. Have a good day, thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I have mentioned it is just an numeric value, a user ID.